# The "nudge someone to run for moderator" thread

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election

Got a user in mind who you think would be a great moderator? Do they need a little encouragement? This thread is a place to gently poke someone in the hope that they consider nominating themselves if they're interested.

Answer (score 1):

@GayotFow (if not already) and @JoErNanO.

Oh and @Dorothy and @Sheik Paul

They all seem like they would make better moderators than I could hope to be.

I'd nominate my boy Reez too, but he's already in the race.

Comment: +1 for Gayot. -1 for Joernano (sorry bro).

Comment: Haha what's wrong with Joernano? And @pnuts yeah I get what you mean, partly the reason I think I'd do well as a mod is because the volume of answers I put out is not on par with the amount of time I'm willing to spend on the site (I spend a lot more time on the site in general than I spend answering) so being a mod wouldn't take away from my contributions at all.